# Passing values into Generic List C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to pass a varying amount of strings into a List and than manipulate these strings.
I am attempting something like this but I think I am doing it wrong:

```
public static void ActivateStateFilter(List<string> lStatelist)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < lStatelist.Count; index++) // Loop with for.
    {
        lStatelist.Add(lStatelist[index]); //Add strings to the list
    }
}
```

This is how I attempt to pass values:

```
ActivateStateFilter(new List<string> {"Active", "Inactive"});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. You pass a list of strings, an d then you want to add those same strings to the same list again?

Comment: Why do you think you are doing it wrong? What do you expect your code to do and what do you observe?

Comment: Could you provide some *samples* of *desired behaivour*?

Comment: I am trying to populate the lStatelist list with varying amount of strings. In this case with just the "Active" and "Inactive" states but it could be more or less from other parts of the code.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I still don't understand. You're passing a list with, say, two items A & B, to a method that populates that very same list with the very same two items, having in the end a list with {A,B,A,B}. So you're making a method that given in input a List with items, duplicates those items and adds them in the List?

Comment: I definitely doing it wrong because I end up with 67108863 values after the loop :( I need the list to be populated only with the strings I pass to it

Comment: Then you don't need any loop at all. Once you do var list=new List<string>(){"Active","Inactive"}; you already have the list.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I just found that I did a silly mistake in the loop (should have done index > lStatelist.Count) and it did solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the existing items how new item in the sended list.
Your code duplicate lStatelist with their existing items.

What are you really trying to do?

if you are trying to insert your string on specific index use this:

```
lStatelist.Insert(index, newstring);
```

Comment: Thanks for help, how do I use the "newstring" in the function correctly?

Comment: @joreldraw if you're not sure of his intent, how can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will throw an *OutOfmemoryException*, because you create an infinite loop.
You are adding the items of a list to the list containing the items… and you are doing this for every item in the list…which will create an infinite loop.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly List<String> _lStateList = new List<String>();

    static void Main( String[] args )
    {
        ActivateStateFilter( new List<String> { "1", "2" } );
    }

    private static void ActivateStateFilter( IEnumerable<String> values )
    {
        _lStateList.AddRange( values );
    }
}
```

This code will add a range of stirng values to _lStateList